# Handling a syscall via ASM (x86) (ebp needed)

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, cpu-registers, system-calls

On x64 I handle syscalls (I hook syscalls and then call them myself) by reserving some space on the stack and copying all the arguments (6) to the stack. I save all the arguments so I can use them later in the code.

This is what my code looks like (intel syntax):

```
push rbp;
mov rbp, rsp;
sub rsp, 64;

mov [rbp - 8], rax;
mov [rbp - 16], rdi;
mov [rbp - 24], rsi;
mov [rbp - 32], rdx;
mov [rbp - 40], rcx;
mov [rbp - 48], r8;
mov [rbp - 56], r9;
...
...
...
```

Note that I'm using `rbp` to access the stack.

Now I'm trying to do the same code for x86. I thought it would be pretty much the same, but then I realized (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/940158) that `ebp` is used for the 6th argument of the syscall, which means I can't use `ebp` to access the stack. Or can I?

How could I achieve the same thing that I'm doing in x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, just (equivalent of your code) do something like:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 64

mov [ebp - 4], eax
mov [ebp - 8], ebx
mov [ebp - 12], ecx
mov [ebp - 16], edx
mov [ebp - 20], esi
mov [ebp - 24], edi
mov eax, [ebp]       ; restore original ebp into eax
mov [ebp - 28], eax  ; and store into “ebp” location
```

What I’m wondering is why you’re referencing the Linux/amd64 and Linux/i386 syscall ABI here, yet seem to be doing the kernel component… (if you’re hacking your own OS, there are better calling conventions for syscalls; if you’re hacking Linux you’ll never see the raw calling arguments). But not the problem at hand, so… ok.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you're restoring the original value of ebp. Can you explain a little bit further? About your second question... if you're really interested, I can explain, but it's a reeeeeeeeeeally long story :)

Comment: You don't (need to) restore it, since you just store it on the stack in a structure. Afterwards, you just always access the values from the structure and use other scratch registers.

Comment: The second line (```mov ebp, esp```) overwrites the value of ```ebp``` with the value of ```esp```. I'd need to restore the original value at some point, right?

Comment: @alexandernst no you push it beforehand, so you can just take that value from the stack. Actually this is what I did when dereferencing `[ebp]`, which is the previous `ebp` value.

Comment: Ah, I see :)  Just one last question. If I wanted to actually restore the value of ```ebp``` (and all other 5 registers) after I'm done, how would I do it?

Comment: Ah, scratch that... I wasn't using my brain when I asked the question :)